# Selenium Webdriver 2.30 unable to identify object on the standard Salesforce lookup pop-up window

Tags: selenium, salesforce, popupwindow

I am using Selenium Webdriver to automate functional TC in Salesforce application.
Test Scenario:
- On a case page, clicking the "Lookup" i.e., search icon opens up standard Salesforce search popup. I need to input specific string to the search field and click "Go" button.

Although I am able to click on the Search button, the script fails to identify any field on the popup.

I used Alert(), getWindowHandle & iterator functions to verify if the driver is working on the popup window. Yes it is.. the popup is is the working window. I could able to confirm this using the Java id for the browser window. But still it fails to identify any fields.

Let me know if any of you faces similar issue and any solution.

Do let me know if you like to have access to my working sandbox. Would be able to manage it.

Thanks, Manju

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that the elements inside the popup window are in a frame.  After switching to the new popup window you need to switch to the frame first before being able to access any of those elements using:

```
WebElement frameLocator = driver.findElement(By.id("searchFrame")); 
driver.switchTo.frame(frameLocator);
```

Answer (score 1):

Further to Bob's answer you'll also then need to switch to the "resultsFrame" in order to use any of the links returned by the search.  Note that in order to switch to a sibling frame you must first go up to the parent of the frameset using:

`driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`

(frameset guidance here: http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/frames-and-webdriver.html)

Answer (score 0):

With Selenium IDE:

I was able to select the Salesforce PopUP with this code:

```
Command:selectPopUp
Target:
Value: Your popUp title
```

And the result frame:

```
Command:selectFrame
Target: name=resultFrame
Value:
```